# A small javascript library for cross platform mouse handling?

Tags: javascript, mouse

Is there a library that gives me a stable API upon which to handle mouse input for Javascript? All I wan't is mouse handling, but if tjere is a great library that doesn't affect other things too much thats also ok.

Comment: fyi... you double posted

Comment: +1 Why the downvotes? IF you don't explain, expect other people to cancel your downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the unnessesary and un explained down vote Anon :/

Comment: Doble posted? I didn't do that its a SO bug on iPhone if that did happen, if anything.

Comment: @Robert Gould: Did you edit the original shortly after posting it. There used to be an open issue with duplicated that *might* have been related to edits.

Comment: Nope, no edit just pressed the GO key on Safari's soft-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Mouse handling*" seems a bit vague, but here's a couple of plugins to the jQuery library that might interest you:

- [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)
- [right-click plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/68)
- [mousewheel](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel)
- [mouse-capture](http://github.com/benanne/jquery-mouse-capture-plugin/tree/master)

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest thing to a real answer :)

Answer (score 0):

[mootools](http://mootools.net)...jquery (I prefer mootools). All are great, and can be customized to contain only the parts you need.

But really, 22k is so big for you?

Comment: Its not size, my module currebtly has no dependencies, so I don't want to force my users to include stuff that may clash with what they are already using :/ Say if I choose MooTools, jQuery folk will be turned off and vice versa. I don't care about size one bit, just don't want to force stuff on people.

Comment: All the major libraries should work with one another without collisions. I tried Jquery and Mootools on the same application without any problems. I believe Dojo will prove the same stability.

Comment: @Itay Moav Perhaps, however, different versions of the *same* library don't play well together.

Comment: @KajMagnus Yes, this is something causing me to grind my teeth alot

Answer (score 0):

[dojotoolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org). But I think this will be a holy war

Comment: Oh yeah, My crusaders are on their way to do DOS attack Muahhahahah.
Seriously, I think it is in our best interest to keep alive most of the major JS libraries. Monopols are not good for us.